# How do I change color of the checkbox background circle?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-theme, android-checkbox

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/black"
            android:text="@string/Agree"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```

I have a CheckBox as above, yes I can change the color of the box when it is clicked, but the background animation circle that appears behind it during checking is still light blue(default color of checkbox if not overridden) How do I change it to match my Checkbox color

Comment: you must post the code that you have already tried,so that others can suggest you changes to meet your requirements.

Comment: I am using Android studio 4.0.1